# Is there a way to reload the content of an item in a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a list where the label of each item tells whether that part of the list has been unlocked. I have another view with a slider that controls the level the user is at. I have the two together in a TabView, so when I change the value in the second view, the items in the first view are not updated. I can make the first view change by closing and re-opening the app, or by refreshing the view in any way, but I can't find a way to do it automatically. Is there a way to make the list update whenever the progress value is changed? I know how to use the `.onChange` code, but I don't know how to make the list update. Here is the code:
ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View{
@AppStorage("Progress") public var progress = 1.0
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        Text("\(Int(progress))")
        Slider(value: $progress, in: 1...5, step: 1)
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(Chapters){ chapter in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChapterItemView(chapter: chapter)
                    } label: {
                        ChapterItemView(chapter: chapter)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Lessons")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Chapter:

```
struct Chapter: Hashable, Identifiable, Decodable{
let id: Int
let num: Int}
var Chapters = [Chapter(id: 1, num: 1), Chapter(id: 2, num: 2), Chapter(id: 3, num: 3), Chapter(id: 4, num: 4), Chapter(id: 5, num: 5)]
```

Item:

```
struct ChapterItemView: View{
var chapter: Chapter
var body: some View{
    HStack{
        if Int(ContentView().progress) >= chapter.num{
            Text("Chapter \(chapter.num)")
        }else{
            Text("\(Image(systemName: "lock.fill"))Chapter \(chapter.num)").opacity(0.5)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

This code should be reproducible, but let me know if it isn't.

Comment: Please show us your code in a [Minimal, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you tried and answer your question.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `@AppStorage progress` also in ChapterView. This will update the view.

`@AppStorage` works similar to `@State` (and obviously saves the value in UserDefaults). You can access the value from any view. If the value changes, the views that use it are redrawn.

```
struct ChapterItemView: View{
    
    @AppStorage("Progress") public var progress = 1.0 // here
    let chapter: Chapter
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            if Int(progress) >= chapter.num{ // and here
                Text("Chapter \(chapter.num)")
            }else{
                Text("\(Image(systemName: "lock.fill"))Chapter \(chapter.num)").opacity(0.5)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know `@AppStorage` values worked between views!